# Why I cant set min value of input type date to today?

Tags: php, date, input

I want to set min date to today but it doesnt work.

Can you please correct me?

My code:

```
echo '<input type="date" name="date" min="'.<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>.'">';
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date is not being printed into the input.

```
echo "<input type='date' name='date' min='".date('Y-m-d')."'>";
```

I also swapped the quotations so you could just use the variable within the echo without involving more.

[Test example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aff1e89a7ffba2ba1a6b65ef47fd14632490f21f)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `<?php` and `?>` inside already existing`<?php ?>` tag.

`<?php echo '<input type="date" name="date" min="' . date("Y-m-d") .' ">'; ?>`